# Javascript - Check which row and column of a table a button is located

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td> Hello world! </td>
<td> <input type="button" id="button" value="myButton" onclick="myFunction();"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a function *myFunction()* that will create an alert (when button is clicked) that says which row and column of the table the button is in.

How can I do that?

Comment: Preferably without using jQuery. Thx

Comment: May I know why you want to know the row and column? Is it to manipulate the `TD`? in which case you dont need the row number and column, but the handle to the TD is enough

Comment: @SajithNair I want to know what row and column the button is in because I have a table with many rows and columns and I want to create a button that will allow the user to remove a row.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was thinking, you dont need all those big loops to add ids to rows and columns, you can direcly remove the parent.parent node of the button, which is the TR

Comment: I have added the code to remove the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to give id's to every row and column and using event.target in your function you can find out which element triggered it.

IMHO instead of triggering a function on every row , you can simply write a common function and subscribe to the click event on the table.

This will reduce your mark up.

Sample Code:-

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr id="Row1">
<td id="Column1"> Hello world! </td>
<td id="Column2"> <input type="button" id="button" value="myButton"> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myTable").click(function(event){
debugger;

    var column=event.target.parentNode.id;
    var row=event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;

});
</script>




Without JQuery:-


<script type="text/javascript">

   var myCell=document.getElementById('button');
    myCell.onclick = function (event) {
       var column=event.target.parentNode.id;
    var row=event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    alert(row);
    alert(column);
    };


</script>
```

See fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/5tBfW/

Comment: OP is not using jQuery

Comment: @Ash suppose table has 100 rows each with 10 columns

Comment: @Rex If a table has 100 rows and 10 columns in each row, I would usually use a for loop :-). Then it would be easy to add the id from there.

Comment: if you don't want to give ID to each and every td, you could do something like this (It uses jquery) : http://cdpn.io/coxnL

Answer (score 1):

To remove the row containing button use this.

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td> Hello world! </td>
<td> <input type="button" id="button" value="myButton" onclick="myFunction(this);"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(elm) {
    elm.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elm.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert that information as myFunction parameter, for example:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="myButton" onclick="myFunction(3,4);">
```

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td> Hello world! </td>
<td> <input type="button" id="button" value="myButton" onclick="myFunction(this);">             </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction (elmt) {
    var tr = $(elmt).parents('tr');
    alert($(tr).index('tr'));
}
</script>
```